# Why did Apocalypse destroy all nuclear weapons?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, character-motivation, x-men-apocalypse

In *X-Men: Apocalypse* movie, when Apocalypse gained control of mankind, he simply used that superpower to destroy all nuclear weapons. At that time, I thought that he was going to enforce peace to mankind (maybe, by taking away freedom, as he was villain).

But later, we saw that he was actually going to use Magneto to destroy most of the mankind (non-mutants and weak mutants). If that was the case, why didn't he simply use those nuclear weapons to do the job?

Comment: I think he was trying to show mutant superiority?

Comment: nuclear weapons are dangerous to mutants on his team.

Answer (score 11):

You've fundamentally misunderstood his plan. Apocalypse' goal isn't to ***destroy*** humanity or cleanse the Earth of life. His primary aim is to *return humanity to a state of bronze-aged barbarism so that he can rule them as he did when he was in Egypt.*

> **Apocalypse:** ... *I was there to spark and fan the flame of man's awakening, to spin the wheel of civilization. And **when the forest
>   would grow rank and in need of clearing for new growth... I was there
>   to set it ablaze.** ... **Everything they've built will fall! And from
>   the ashes of their world, we'll build a better one!***

His idea of an *ideal* society is that of the [Old Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egypt) (around 5000 years ago).

> **Storm:** *Where did you come from?*
>
> **Apocalypse:** *The time before man lost his way.*

He recognises that even with no weapons to oppose him, the world is simply too cosmopolitan to be dominated.

> **Storm:** *You can't save the world, just going around killing people. There's laws, system and place for that kind of thing.*
>
> **Apocalypse:** *My child, why do you enslave yourself?*
>
> **Storm:** *What are you doing?*
>
> **Apocalypse:**  *Making you stronger. My goddess.*
>
> **Storm:** *Yes. You were right. **The time has passed. There is no room for gods.***

He despairs of our violent ways

> **Apocalypse:** *It's always the same. And now all this. **No more stones. Not more spears. No more slings. No more swords. No more
>   weapons! No more systems!** No more! No more superpowers.*

And there's the slim possibility that these weapons might be used against him.

> **Apocalypse:** *You can fire your arrows from the Tower of Babel. **BUT YOU CAN NEVER STRIKE GOD!***

Comment: `his primary aim is to return humanity to a state of bronze-aged barbarism` ~> Why couldn't he achieve that with nuclear weapons?

Comment: @IAMGROOT - Because most Hollywood producers are under the wrong-headed impression that a thermonuclear war will result in centuries of nuclear winter and everyone in the world dying.

Comment: @IAMGROOT I disagree with the comment above, I strongly feel the specific reason that Apocalypse did not use the nuclear weapons to bring about his goal was because they were man made. His entire foundation of his view was that *mutants* were the ones with the power, and using mans weapons instead of a mutant's gift supports the idea that man has the power.

Comment: @Ender - Using nukes would have resulted in radiation. His way is clean and just as (in fact more) effective. The risk is that if he leaves them in place, someone might try to use them, either against him or mistakenly against each other.

Comment: @Valorum You misunderstand me. I do not disagree with your *answer*. I disagree with your *comment*.

Comment: @Valorum Do you really think what Magneto was doing couldn't spill radiation? Earth has very very large amounts of radioactive materials.

Comment: @Ender If you can back that up with quotes, that can be answer.

Comment: @IamGroot - Magneto was using (non-radioactive) iron to churn up the surface of the earth and bury all the structures.

Comment: @Valorum You are talking like Uranium mines are much deeper than Iron mines...

Comment: @IAMGROOT - I didn't write the thing. Go yell at them.

Answer (score 4):

Apocalypse has disdain for tools and weapons.

> Apocalypse: They put so much faith in their... tools and their... machines.

More specifically, he views weapons as a way for the weak to wield power:

> Apocalypse: Weapons?
>
> Reporter: Never before has man possess so much power. With Soviet Union and the United States being superpowers...
>
> Apocalypse: Superpowers? The weak have taken the Earth. For this, I was betrayed. False gods. Idols. No more. I have returned.

then:

> Apocalypse: It's always the same. And now all this. No more stones. Not more spears. No more slings. No more swords. No more weapons! No more systems! No more! No more superpowers.

On the other hand he is very fond of mutant powers:

> Apocalypse: I want you... To feel the full reach of your power. You've only have a taste of your true strength. Unlike others who seek to control you. I want to set you free.

and:

> Apocalypse: To tell the strongest among you... Those with the greatest power. This earth will be yours.

It would be hypocritical of him to use nuclear weapons (the tools of the "weak") to achieve his goals. His vision is that the strong will rule and the weak will perish, and the way he defines strength only refers to innate abilities (even if he is enhancing them). It is because of these beliefs that he chooses to use Magneto's power rather than nukes to decimate the planet.